# Lightspeed breaks Octave Forge package installation- binary operator '==' not implemented

Tags: octave

I'm getting the following error while trying to install an Octave package:

```
binary operator '==' not implemented for 'cell' by 'scalar' operations
error: called from
    glob at line 62 column 1
    install at line 60 column 11
    pkg at line 437 column 9
```

This is happening for several packages- struct and optim for example, whether or not I install from a local download or from Forge.

Note this is happening if I load the [Lightspeed library](https://github.com/tminka/lightspeed) (version 2.8), which replaces the builtin `glob` function.

Comment: What is the question? The obvious solution to your problem is to not install the Lightspeed toolkit, or remove it from the path when installing packages. Other than that, file a bug report at the Lightspeed toolkit GitHub page. Though the toolbox is designed for MATLAB, not Octave.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I agree, but the general principle is that if a 'module' breaks an 'environment', it's the environment's fault and it needs to be fixed. So this is also worth reporting to Octave as an _octave_ bug, to replace use of `glob` with `builtin('glob')` in their codebase.

Comment: (having said that, there is no guarantee Lightspeed will be compatible with octave even then, but that's another matter)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou very much disagree with "the general principle is that if a 'module' breaks an 'environment', it's the environment's fault". In this case, the environment is the language and shadowing core functions is supported (that's how the nan package works for example). It's the module that needs to be careful and ensure that if you shadow functions they keep their signature. But I don't see where that "general principle" holds at all in the general cases.

Comment: @carandraug well ok, let's agree it's contentious: Octave _may_ be a special case, complicated by the fact that to an extent it is forced to take careful steps to be compatible with matlab, such as in this case. But in general, to give an unrelated example, if for instance a piece of software manages to crash an entire OS, that is an OS failure first and foremost, and an app failure second. So in the same vein of thought, if octave internals rely on appropriate 'globbing', then steps against shadowing such a core function should be taken; this is hardly the same as shadowing a 'mean' function!

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou that's not a fair comparison. Lighspeed is not a program, it's a library. If you want to compare against an OS, lightspeed is akin to a kernel module. And if a module crashes the kernel, that's the module failure and not the kernel.

Comment: @carandraug I don't disagree; and any 'analogy' one makes will always fall short w.r.t. specifics. But I feel that if "glob" is used in such a 'core' way to the system (so as to break the installation of packages if overloaded), then this is not robust. It's one thing to allow shadowing of userspace functions of a mathematical nature intentionally to enhance / differentiate functionality, and its a completely different thing to have a system which is so fragile that the accidental shadowing of a command can cause the entire package installation and loading system to break apart.

Comment: 1. Pleasently surprised to have this many responses, even if my question was apparently a little confusing and rubbish. Clearly Octave has a strong community

2. I misused 'toolkit', Lightspeed is just a library used by some ML researchers

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to test this extensively on my machine, but the LightSpeed "toolkit" seems to be nothing more than a collection of 'files' (albeit needing initial compilation).

Adding this collection to the path causes it to shadow a core octave function (`glob`) which happens not to exist in matlab.

A way around it is to create a namespace, i.e. instead of adding the offending items to the path directly, wrap them around a folder with a plus ('+') in front of the name (e.g. "+Lightspeed"), and add that to the path. You can then call all Lightspeed functions qualified by that namespace, e.g. "Lightspeed.digamma".

In theory this should work; it's up to the particular implementation how sanely they handled relative references etc, but in theory it should be fine.

Alternatively, you could just modify Lightspeed code a bit and replace all occurences of `glob` with `Lglob` or something like that.

Or, as Cris suggested, you could try removing Lightspeed from the path and only load it whenever you need to use one of its functions (or `cd` to its folder before executing Lightspeed related things).

As pointed out in the comments, this is worth raising as a bug, both to Lightspeed<sup>1</sup> and to Octave.

---

<sub>1: Though presumably Lightspeed will just say they don't support Octave and you're welcome to try fixing the code yourself</sub>

Comment: I really don't think there is a bug in GNU Octave here. Overloading is part of the language design. If I would write a plugin/library which overwrites a function which is used by one of your scripts, would you really say the problem is inside your skript and not it is my "buggy overloaded function"?

Comment: @Andy please join the 'discussion' above, you're in agreement with Carandraug (and I don't disagree over the whole spectrum). Perhaps this would be a useful discussion to have in the octave mailing list.

Comment: +1 for the `+Lightspeed` namespace suggestion. I think this is good practice for all Matlab libraries, regardless of whether they care about Octave compatibility: it avoids collisions with not only built-in Matlab/Octave functions, but also with functions that might be defined in other user-created libraries, the names of which Lightspeed couldn't know about ahead of time. However, this needs to be done at the library level: in Matlab, all namespaced functions must be explicitly qualified everywhere, even when called from functions in the same namespace.

Comment: And here is the thread on the mailinglist: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Robustness-against-accidental-shadowing-of-core-functions-tc4689286.html